# Question about the Perspectives add-on, is this dangerous?

Tags: tls, certificates, browser-extensions, plugins

When I visited Google and Facebook, and then clicked on the Perspectives add-on button to check the certificate information, I saw this:

[image]

What does this mean? Shouldn't it have more "graph" lines? Why just two? Is this secure? Do I have to worry about this?

Comment: My guess would be that the other Perspectives servers couldn't check the certificate because of their geolocation and both Google and Facebook using distributed networks and load-balanced servers, so their requests would be served via a different server with a different certificate and couldn't be cross-checked with the one you're seeing in your browser. Doesn't look like anything to worry about to me, there's no _red flag_ warnings displayed anywhere. BTW I cropped the image you were attaching to remove your info in the taskbar. ;)